# SAXParser multiple tagnames what to do?

Tags: saxparser

i have an XML-File with the following entries:

```
<country>
    <isoCode>US</isoCode>
    <name>United States</isoCode>
</country>
<language>
    <isoCode>EN</isoCode>
    <name>English</isoCode>
</language>
```

how can i see which isoCode it is? and which name it is?

if the open-tag isoCode exists i set a boolean isIsoCode to true
if its true i want to set the isoCode in the endElement method.

but how can i know now which i have to set. the language isoCode 
or the country isocode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `startElement` method, when it's called for the country or language tag you can set a boolean isCountry and/or isLanguage to distinguish which is current.